# IIS7.5 default.aspx redirects to root, but only with www

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I noticed that when entering my site in the browser as "www.mysite.com", that's exactly the way it stays, but when entering "mysite.com", it redirects to "www.mysite.com/default.aspx". Can anyone explain to me

1. How come the "www" doesn't show the default.aspx, although I haven't set up any url rewrites, and
2. how come the "www" behavior is different from the non-"www" behavior.

My goal is that the non-"www" should also not show the "default.aspx".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it show when you use "http: // mysite.com" ?

Comment: it shows http://www.mysite.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS manager, here is link [How to: Open IIS Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Next on left panel select you web site and double-click on "Default Document" icon

[image]

Here you can remove all default pages and add one you have desired.

[image]

You actualy don't have to have any default page.

Hope this helps!